# dynamic flexibility in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have recently started learning programming and chose .NET with Visual Studio Express.  I am trying to write a CSV Parser as a learning experience and it's giving me a lot more trouble than I expected.  I am starting with the reader.  One thing I am doing differently in my parser is that I am not using quotes.  I am escaping commas with a backslash, backslashes with a backslash, and line breaks with a backslash.  For example, if a comma is preceded by an even number of backslashes it is a field and I halve any blocks of backslashes.  If it's odd, it's not end of field and I still halve blocks of backslashes.  I'm not sure how robust this will be if I can ever get it working, except I'm only learning at this point and I'm looking at it mostly as an exercise in manipulating data structures.

I have a question in reference to the code snippet at the bottom of this post and how to make it not so static and limiting and still compile and run for me.

The line of code that reads:

```
var contents = (String)fileContents;
```

I keep trying to make it more dynamic to increase flexibility and make it something like this:

```
var contents = (otherVariableThatCouldChangeTypeAtRuntime.GetType())fileContents;
```

Is there something I can do to get it to do this and still compile?  Maybe something like Option Infer from VB.NET might help, except I can't find that.

Also, I have written this in VB.NET as well.  It seems to me that VB.NET allows me a considerably more dynamic style than what I've posted below, such as not having to type var over and over again and not having to keep casting my index counting variable into an integer over and over again if I shut off Option Strict and Option Explicit as well as turn on Option Infer.  For example, C# won't let me type something analogous to the following VB.NET code even though I know the methods and properties I will be calling at run-time will be there at run-time.

```
    Dim contents As Object = returnObjectICantDetermineAtComplieTime()
    contents.MethodIKnowWillBeThereAtRunTime()
```

Can I do these things in C#?  Anyways, here's the code and thanks in advance for any responses.

```
    public class Widget
    {
        public object ID { get; set; }
        public object PartNumber { get; set; }
        public object VendorID { get; set; }
        public object TypeID { get; set; }
        public object KeyMarkLoc { get; set; }

        public Widget() { }
    }

    public object ReadFromFile(object source)
        {
            var fileContents = new FileService().GetFileContents(source);
            object records = null;

            if (fileContents == null)
                return null;

            var stringBuffer = "";
            var contents = (String)fileContents;

            while (contents.Length > 0 && contents != "\r\n")
            {
                for (object i = 0; (int)i < contents.Length; i=(int)i+1 )
                {
                    object character = contents[(int)i];

                    if (!stringBuffer.EndsWith("\r\n"))
                    {
                        stringBuffer += character.ToString();
                    }

                    if (stringBuffer.EndsWith("\r\n"))
                    {
                        var bSlashes = getBackSlashes(stringBuffer.Substring(0, stringBuffer.Length - 4));
                        stringBuffer = stringBuffer.Substring(0, stringBuffer.Length - 4);
                        if ((int)bSlashes % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                contents = contents.Substring(stringBuffer.Length+2);
                records = records == null ? getIncrementedList(new List<object>(), getNextObject(getFields(stringBuffer))) : getIncrementedList((List<object>)records, getNextObject(getFields(stringBuffer)));
            }

            return records;
        }

        private Widget getNextRecord(object[] fields)
        {
            var personStudent = new Widget();

            personStudent.ID = fields[0];
            personStudent.PartNumber = fields[1];
            personStudent.VendorID = fields[2];
            personStudent.TypeID = fields[3];
            personStudent.GridPath = fields[4];

            return personStudent;
        }

        private object[] getFields(object buffer)
        {
            var fields = new object[5];
            var intFieldCount = 0;
            var fieldVal = "";
            var blocks = buffer.ToString().Split(',');
            foreach (var block in blocks) 
            {
                var bSlashes = getBackSlashes(block);

                var intRemoveCount = (int)bSlashes / 2;
                if ((int)bSlashes % 2 == 0) // Delimiter
                {
                    fieldVal += block.Substring(0, block.Length - intRemoveCount);
                    fields[intFieldCount] += fieldVal;
                    intFieldCount++;
                    fieldVal = "";
                }
                else // Part of Field
                {
                    fieldVal += block.Substring(0, block.Length - intRemoveCount - 1) + ",";
                }
            }

            return fields;
        }

        private object getBackSlashes(object block)
        {
            object bSlashes = block.ToString().Length == 0 ? new int?(0) : null;
            for (object i = block.ToString().Length - 1; (int)i>-1; i=(int)i-1)
            {
                if (block.ToString()[(int)i] != '\\') return bSlashes = bSlashes == null ? 0 : bSlashes;
                bSlashes = bSlashes == null ? 1 : (int)bSlashes + 1;
            }

            return bSlashes;
        }
    }
```

Here is the web service code.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public object GetFileContents(object source)
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(source.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Dim contents As Object = returnObjectICantDetermineAtComplieTime()
> contents.MethodIKnowWillBeThereAtRunTime()
> ```

You can do this with the `dynamic` type.
See for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx